# Batch normalising multiple audio and video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have hundreds of mp4 videos and wavs which are all different volumes. I want to normalise them using ffmpeg.

To normalise one video I use the following code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:a loudnorm output.mp4
```

Is there an ffmpeg code to normalise all of them on macOS?

Comment: `ffmpeg` has no batch mode because it is expected that users will use the capabilities of their shell/OS to do that. So answer depends on your OS.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am using Mac Os. I appreciate that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service which is why I spent some time searching for the answer and finally provided the code I was able to show which is the code above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Bash *for loop*. This example assumes all inputs are in the same directory (no recursion).

```
mkdir output
for i in *.{mp4,wav}; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -filter:a loudnorm -c:v copy "output/$i"; done
```

Adapted from [How do you convert an entire directory with `ffmpeg`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)

Comment: Understood llogan, just seen your message so apologise for the delay. Many thanks